# DimpleJS - how to animate graph and download the graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dimple.js

I have a few DimpleJS graphs (line, pie, bar etc.). How do I:

1. Animate the graph draw - Most of the D3 examples I've seen appear before the user's eyes i.e. you can see the bar chart's height increasing, the timeline getting drawn etc. How do I do that in DimpleJS? I tried storyboard but that doesn't seem to be working.
2. How do I give the user an option to download the graph (as jpg/png/excel etc.) ?

Thanks-in-advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. When you call [chart.draw](https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/wiki/dimple.chart#draw), provide a number for the first argument for the number of milliseconds to transition. It defaults to 0 so by default there is no transition.
2. This is not something provided by Dimple or D3 natively. There are other libraries you can look into which provide some of that functionality, like the one referenced by (and detailed in) this blog post : http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/01/21/convert-svg-to-png/